Vertical Lines in Proportional Hazard Assumption Test
I ran a Anderson-Gill survival analysis. When checking if the proportional hazard assumption is met, I got the following plot:

The Betas at the very of end of my study are for sure wrong. What did I do wrong?

Welcome to Cross Validated! Please edit the question to say more about the nature of the underlying data (what are the events, how many individuals, how many events, how many predictors in the model, etc.) and the rationale for choosing an Anderson-Gill model. That type of model makes a very strong assumption about mutual independence of observations within an individual, which might not hold for your data. Also, the absolute magnitudes of the beta values are extremely large even before the major pileup/drop at the latest times.
